# Can I truncate long file names in ls listing

Tags: filenames, display-settings

I have a number of files with very long names. Please, is there a way to use ls -C and truncate the file names to get more columns for an overall view?

Or is there a better way to get a compact listing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
ls | cut -c1-20 | columns -W "${COLUMNS:-80}"
```

[image: columns example]

(that's `columns` with an `s` from GNU autogen). Or:

```
ls | cut -c1-20 | column -c"${COLUMNS:-80}"
```

[image: column example]
Using `column` as found on BSDs or in `bsdmainutils` on Debian or its derivatives.

`zsh` also has support to print things in columns, and has `l[width]` and `r[width]` left/right padding and truncating operators which combined with the `m` flag pad/truncate to a given display width taking into account the width of each character like BSD `column` does, so you could define a function like:

```
setopt extendedglob
c() print -rC$[COLUMNS/(($1)+2)] -- "${(mr[$1])@[2,-1]}"
```

And use it as:

```
c 20 *.txt
```

To print the list of `.txt` files in columns, padded/truncated to 20 characters.

And to make it a bit crazier, you could add:

```
command_not_found_handler() {[[ $1 = <-> ]] && c "$@"}
```

That way, you can also do:

```
20 *
```

[image: zsh example]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. On my Fedora 12 system I used  the ls | cut -c1-20 | columns -W "${COLUMNS:-80}" line, and got all my files on one screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an 80 column screen, I like to use

`ls -F | perl -lne 's/(.{34}).*/$1... /s ; print' | column -x | more`

[image]

use `ls -FC` instead to sort by recency

---

*(Sidenote: my `ls` already scrolls because it's aliased to `ls -CF --color | more -r`. Not sure that's best practice...)*